# django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I get an error in my User

AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'objetcs'

I get the error in forms.py when I try to use my User.

// forms.py //

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from . import models

User = get_user_model()

class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Perfil
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('usuario',)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget= forms.PasswordInput(),
        label='Senha'
    )
    
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget= forms.PasswordInput(),
        label='Confirmar senha'
    )

    def __init__(self, usuario=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.usuario = usuario
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password', 'password2', 'email',)
         
        usuario_db = User.objetcs.filter(username=usuario_data).first() **<-- here I get the error**
        email_db = User.objetcs.filter(email=email_data).first()
```

Comment: You have a typo. Is not `.objetcs` but `.objects`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access properties of a `NoneType` object and the reason why it is `NoneType` is because the User object you tried to query in this line of code does not exist:

```py
    usuario_db = User.objects.filter(username=usuario_data).first()
```

This is because either:

1. `username` field was not provided in the submitted form, hence when you try to retrieve it with:

```py
    usuario_data = cleaned.get('username')
```

You are getting `None`.
I would suggest making this field required or providing custom validation if you need to.

2. Second potential reason is that there is no such user in your DB with the provided username. You can either check if such a user exists before attempting to accessing any of its properties like this:

```py
    usuario_db = User.objects.filter(username=usuario_data).first()
    ... # do something
        if usuario_db is not None:
            if usuario_data != usuario_db.username:
            ... # do something
```

Or you can use `.get()` and catch an error:

```py
    try:
        usuario_db = User.objects.get(username=usuario_data)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # handle error
```